# Read only visible columns in XLSX file

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I am using `Spreadsheet::XLSX` to read excel files and rewriting it to another excel using `Excel::Writer::XLSX`.In that excel file some of the columns are hidden, but during writing the hidden columns also becomes visible.

Is there anyway using `Spreadsheet::XLSX` to read only visible columns.I am unable to find the any way in documentation.

Comment: That thing seems to be not very current and not very powerful. Maybe you need to hack that yourself. Contact the author and ask if it's on github so you can supply a patch.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  If so, Win32::OLE will let you use the VB Runtime library that will let you do anything VBA can do, including this.